# What is the fastest way to generate an POST or GET SOAP XML payload for SuiteTalk Web services?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, suitetalk

Hopefully someone can help me.

I am currently using POSTMAN to run SOAP web service tests on NetSuite.

Annoyingly, I am having to generate the body of an XML request from scratch, and would really like a method whereby a basic template is generated for me, and I simply fill in the gaps. Creating an XML web request from scratch is prone to errors hence my question. I tried SOAPUI but it does not

Any ideas is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

hope you remember me!! The easiest way would be to download any of the existing working SOAP web request from any running build and modify that to suit your need. There is no out of the box built in template that you could build on at least as per my knowledge. Please specify the record for which you are building the SOAP request

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not use POSTMAN.

I used to do a lot of this and what I'd do is:

- generate the java client for SuiteTalk
- install a recording proxy (I think WireMock does this -- the one I used to use doesn't seem to be around anymore)
- use JUnit tests to hit SuiteTalk

  - in the test setup override the SSL config to ignore host name verification
  - test an API call
  - extract the complete working SOAP from the proxy logs
  - templatize the SOAP and use it where needed.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Would you kindly point the direction of the "Java Client" you speak of please? A "recording proxy" - I will do some research on this. One other method I used was extracting the template from middleware like DellBoomi or Jitterbit, where an integration platform exists, but my current client does not use these :-(